# Dividing column intro groups that contains time values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to divide column L according to specific time ranges and put it in Another column.

Time ranges:

```
00:00 - 05:00 => 0
05:00 - 10:00 => 1
10:00 - 15:00 => 2   
15:00 - 20:00 => 3
20:00 - 00:00 => 4
```

I've tried with this formula in excel, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
=IF(time(0;0;0)<L2<=time(5;0;0); 0;IF(time(5;0;0)<L2<=time(10;0;0); 1;IF(time(10;0;0)<L2<=time(15;0;0); 2;IF(time(15;0;0)<L2<=time(20;0;0); 3;IF(time(20;0;0)<L2<=time(0;0;0);4))))).
```

Example of data and expected output:

```
L       K
00:00   0
00:00   0
07:50   1
00:00   0
00:00   0
06:16   1
00:00   0
14:20   2
15:50   3
06:10   1
16:24   3
```

Thx!

Comment: Are the values in column L just times or datetimes that need the time peeled out of them? What do you mean by *Another column*? Should each group be in another column?

Comment: Just times (hh:mm). I'm in column K and using column L as reference.

Comment: Tried to shorten it down:

    =IF(time(0;0;0)<L2;0;IF(time(5;0;0)<L2;1;IF(time(10;0;0)<L2;2;IF(time(15;0;0)<L2;3;4))))

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In column K use this,

```
=IF(L2<=TIME(5; 0; 0); 0; IF(L2<=TIME(10; 0; 0); 1; IF(L2<=TIME(15; 0; 0); 2; IF(L2<=TIME(20; 0; 0); 3;  4))))
```

An `IF` formula stops evaluating once it finds something that is true. If a time is less than 5:00 AM then it is true and zero is returned. The next check (for less than 10:00 AM) does not need to check if it is also greater than 5:00 AM; that was done previously and you wouldn't be checking the 10:00 AM criteria unless it was true.

Alternates:

```
=INT(K2/TIME(5; 0; 0))
=INT((K2*24)/5)
```